# extracting words from a prolog structure

Tags: prolog, dcg

i have been set a task of natural language parsing in Prolog. so far i have the program working to an extent. So far it will print  `sentence(noun_phrase(det(the), np2(noun(cat))), verb_phrase(verb(sat), pp(prep(on), noun_phrase(det(the), np2(noun(mat))))))` if i input a list of `[the,cat,sat,on,the,mat]`, which is fine.

the next task i have to do is to extract the keywords from the sentence, ie extract the noun in the noun phrase, the verb in the verb phrase and the noun in the verb phrase, so i could return a list: [cat,sat,mat]. Could anybody give me a hand getting started because im very stuck with this. thanks!

my current code is:

```
sentence(S,sentence((NP), (VP))):-
   nl,
np(S, NP, R),
vp(R, VP, []),
write('sentence('), nl, write('   '), write((NP))
      ,nl,write('    '), write((VP)),nl,write('  ').

np([X | S], noun_phrase(det(X), NP2), R) :-
    det(X),
    np2(S, NP2, R).
np(S, NP, R) :-
    np2(S, NP, R).
np(S, np(NP, PP), R) :-
    append(X, Y, S), /* Changed here - otherwise possible endless recursion */
    pp(Y, PP, R),
    np(X, NP, []).

np2([X | R], np2(noun(X)), R) :-
    noun(X).
np2([X | S], np2(adj(X), NP), R) :-
    adj(X),
    np2(S, NP, R).

pp([X | S], pp(prep(X), NP), R):-
    prep(X),
    np(S, NP, R).

vp([X | R], verb_phrase(verb(X)), R) :- /* Changed here - added the third argument */
    verb(X).
vp([X | S], verb_phrase(verb(X), PP), R) :-
    verb(X),
    pp(S, PP, R).
vp([X | S], verb_phrase(verb(X), NP), R) :-
    verb(X),
    np(S, NP, R).


det(the).
det(with).
noun(cat).
noun(mat).
verb(sat).
prep(on).
adj(big).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiple successive `write/1` calls, consider using `format/2`. However, it is usually best to avoid side-effects, and instead to think in terms of relations. To describe the relation between your sentence structures and lists, consider using DCG notation:

```
sentence(sentence(NP, VP)) -->
    np(NP),
    vp(VP).

np(noun_phrase(det(D), np2(noun(N)))) --> [D, N].
... etc.
```

and then using the program like `?- phrase(sentence(S), List).`. You can then use the program in all directions and for example also check whether a given list corresponds to a sentence structure, which you cannot do so easily if you just write output to the screen.

Comment: ok,thanks for the reply. however i'd rather not change the notation of what i already have because time is an issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You could

a) build the list while parsing

b) take a verbatim visit of the syntax tree built

c) write a generic visit using (for instance) =.. (*univ*) and findall.

To follow a) change your current program, adding the list after the syntax tree.

A sketch of b) (b stay for *boring*):

```
extract(sentence(NP, VP), L) :-
 extract(NP, A), extract(VP, B), append(A, B, L)
extract(noun_phrase(_, noun(N)), [N]).
etc etc...
```

The generic visit:

```
extract(SynTree, O) :-
  SynTree =.. [F|As],
  findall(R, (member(M, As), extract(M, R)), Rs),
  ((F = noun ; F = verb) -> As = [K], L = [K|Rs] ; L = Rs),
  flatten(L, O).
```